I cannot change the network connection anymore using nm-applet
I used to use the nm-applet to manage my network connections and everything was fine.
After some unspecified event I can't manage the connections anymore.
Suspect events:

I installed, configured, activated and finally removed TigerVNC.
I edited, via the Settings app (Suse, KDE Plasma on X) one of the
connections, specifying that the password was to be shared among
users (always me :).

Effects:

The nm-applet is useless,

I cannot switch connections, or even disconnect from the current one
(that alas is the slowest that I have available…).
I can turn off the wireless and/or set Airplane mode, but
I'm still connected.
When I use the applet to show download and upload speed for
the active connection, the applet reports zero and zero even
if I'm searching a solution on the Internet!


A second instance of nm-applet appeared in the system tray,
but it's not the same as the "original" one that has an elaborate
graphical interface, the new one has simply a pop-up menu.
The system settings app provided by Plasma works fine but for
network settings. When I try to access network settings the app
freezes for a longish while, it temporarily freezes also when
I try to access the different interfaces that I'd like to change,
and eventually when I change a setting  the [Apply] button is
greyed out (and sometimes the app dies).

All in all, it seems that root has taken control of my network
connections… or was it systemd? I remember that systemd was involved in enabling my temporary VNC server.
What have I done to remedy the problem? I've tried the Windows way, shut down and restart, obviously to no avail.
What have I to do to restore the previous situation?

Additional information
Permissions, the command was run from my user account
01:47 Thu, Aug 15 ~/ $ nmcli general permissions
PERMISSION                                                        VALUE 
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.checkpoint-rollback                auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-connectivity-check  no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network             no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-statistics          no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wifi                no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wimax               no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wwan                no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control                    no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.reload                             auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.global-dns         auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.hostname           auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own                auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system             auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.sleep-wake                         no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.scan                          auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open                    auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected               auth  
08:02 Thu, Aug 15 ~/ $ 

Errors when using the graphical app nm-connection-editor as my usual, ordinary user account
01:45 Thu, Aug 15 ~/ $ nm-connection-editor 

(nm-connection-editor:25711): dbind-WARNING **: 01:46:09.249: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /root/.cache/at-spi/bus_0: Permission denied

** (nm-connection-editor:25711): WARNING **: 01:46:43.155: Couldn't fetch secrets: Timeout was reached
** Message: 01:46:43.436: Cannot save connection due to error: Invalid setting Wi-Fi Security: invalid wpa-psk: invalid key-length 0. Must be [8,63] bytes or 64 hex digits

** (nm-connection-editor:25711): WARNING **: 01:46:43.438: Failed to get zones from FirewallD: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
01:47 Thu, Aug 15 ~/ $

